React - Recharts How to prevent active bar to change while still hovering on the tooltip
I am using this chart, the problem is my tooltip contains some links, and it's width extends the other bars, and when i want to click on the link, the tooltip changes to the next bar's tooltip.
Is there a way to fix prevent changing the tooltip while still hovering on a previous one ?
<ResponsiveContainer>
  <BarChart
    data={data}
  >
    <XAxis>
      dataKey="month"
      type="category"
      tick={<CustomTikc/>}
    />
    <Tooltip
      content={<CustomTooltip {...props} />}
      wrapperStyle={{pointerEvents: "auto"}}
      position={{y:100}}
    />
    { dataKeys.map((dataKey, index) => (<Bar dataKey={dataKey} fill={COLORS[index]} key={index} />) }
  </BarChar>
</ResponsiveContainer>

I tried to do it programmatically, but i don't have access to programmatically change the activeIndex which is the current active bar.
